# Apple Safari Buttons onclick takes to long

Tags: html, mobile, safari

i have a simple system to register who is present at a party.
I created an easy numkeypad with buttons, and that works. But when I try it in Safari (or any other mobile browser), it takes about a second before I can press the next button. It has to be quick, so this is too long.

Is there any way to shorten this "waiting" time between button presses.

Comment: Can you provide some code or a url to a live example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click` events are delayed in mobile browsers due to the fact the browser has to ensure the user isn't double-tapping or tap-holding an element.

I have written a jQuery plugin that can handle touch and mouse events in a convenient way, and allows you to bind one event to trigger without a delay (`tap`). You can check it out here:

https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Mobile-Events

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But if i use only $("button").tap(), it doesnt work in non-mobile browsers anymore...

Comment: It should do. Can you share your code or perhaps provide a link?

Comment: http://quick.thijsdemaa.nl/tap_problem.php
I see it works now, but when I shift the mouse whilst clicking, it doesnt work

Comment: Erm, you're not including the jQuery library I wrote... It won't work without it.

Comment: Yes, I did... I just named it tap.js

Comment: If I try to do it quickly, and I move my mouse while clicking, it doesnt execute the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27629/discussion-between-thijsdemaa-and-benm)